# pass only a member of std::vector's of struct to function (C++)

Tags: c++, function, vector, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct myStruct {

    // there are other members as well
    float U, V, W;
}
std::vector <myStruct> myVec;
myVec.resize(num);
```

I want to pass only myVec[].U for all myVec's to a function.

Comment: You mean, you want to pass an array of `U`s?

Comment: To clarify, you want to pass a `vector<float>` to a function, where each entry in the new vector contains the value of the member `U` from `myVec`?

Comment: @Shibli: if there's a particular parameter type that the function must take, please state the signature of the function in the question. It affects the answer -- clearly my answer doesn't help if the function is for example required to take precisely a `float*` as parameter.

Comment: why not simply pass `myVec` and save yourself a lot of effort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a pair of iterators to the function:

```
struct pick_U : std::unary_function<myStruct&, float&> {
    float &operator()(myStruct &ms) const { return ms.U; }
};

your_function(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myVec.begin(), pick_U()),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myVec.end(), pick_U()),
    ... other args ...
};
```

Then `your_function` can iterate over the floats.

Answer (score 2):

Since an array of floats requires contiguous storage, and your vector `myVec` does not store the `U`s contiguously, you need to make a copy:

```
std::vector<float> uv;
uv.reserve(myVec.size());

for (auto const & s : myVec) { uv.push_back(s.U); }

// now use uv.data() if your callee needs a float*
```

On older compilers you have to say:

```
for (std::vector<myStruct>::const_iterator it = myVec.begin(), end = myVec.end(); it != end; ++it)
    uv.push_back(it->U);
```

You may also have to say `&uv[0]` instead of `uv.data()` to get a raw pointer to the array.

Comment: What if I want to modify `U`s. I mean, something like passing by reference.

Comment: @Shibli: You're free to modify the contents of `uv`, though obviously that won't propagate back to `myVec`. If your consumer function is happy with a C++ `vector`, then you can use a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>>` instead and insert `std::ref(s.U)`. With raw C-arrays you can't really achieve that, and you'd have to copy the changes back manually, or use an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

---

First option: Redesign so that instead of

```
struct myStruct 
{

    // there are other members as well
    float U, V, W;
}

std::vector <myStruct> myVec;
```

You have

```
struct myStructs {

    // there are other members as well
    std::vector<float> Us, Vs, Ws;
}

myStructs allOfMyStructs;
```

Then you can simply pass the Us vector.
(This is also known as data oriented programming)

---

Second option: copy all of the U elements into one vector.

```
std::vector<float> Us;
for (auto iter = myVec.begin(); iter != myVec.end(); iter++)
   Us.push_back(iter->U);
```

Then you simply pass the Us vector.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code example and your explanation, you want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct myStruct {
    float u;
};

void foo(float& f) {
    f = 44.1;
}

int main() {
    vector<myStruct> myVec(5, myStruct());
    for (auto& i : myVec) {
        foo(i.u);
    }
    for (const auto& i : myVec) {
        cout << i.u << endl;
    }
}

// g++ -Wall -Wextra test.cc -o test -O3 -s -std=c++0x
```

for example.

As in, all you wanted to know how to do is how to pass myVec[n].U to a function.

But, looking at your comments and other posts, I'm not sure.